# Windows ffmpeg extension added in php extension issue

Tags: php, wampserver, php-extension

I am using wamp and 5.5.12 php version

Download php_ffmpeg.dll from somewhere and copied in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext
restarted wamp and computer as well. 
but it says php_ffmpeg.dll is missing any help ?

I am using 64bit system any offical place to look for php_ffmpeg.dll 64bit version
?

the code:

```
 /**
  * FFMPEG-PHP Test Script
  *    
  */
  echo "GD: ", extension_loaded('gd') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
  echo "XML: ", extension_loaded('xml') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';
 echo "zip: ", extension_loaded('zip') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';

echo "ffmpeg: ", extension_loaded('ffmpeg') ? 'OK' : 'MISSING', '<br>';

// Check if the ffmpeg-php extension is loaded first
 // extension_loaded('ffmpeg') or die('Error in loading ffmpeg');

 // Determine the full path for our video
 // $vid = realpath('./vid2.avi');
 $vid = realpath('input.flv');

 // d then display the information about the video clip.
  $ffmpegInstance = new ffmpeg_movie($vid);
  echo "getDuration: " . $ffmpegInstance->getDuration() . "<br />".
  "getFrameCount: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameCount() . "<br />".
  "getFrameRate: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFrameRate() . "<br />".
  "getFilename: " . $ffmpegInstance->getFilename() . "<br />".
  "getComment: " . $ffmpegInstance->getComment() . "<br />".
  "getTitle: " . $ffmpegInstance->getTitle() . "<br />".
  "getAuthor: " . $ffmpegInstance->getAuthor() . "<br />".
 "getCopyright: " . $ffmpegInstance->getCopyright() . "<br />".
 "hasAudio: " . $ffmpegInstance->hasAudio();
```

Comment: Your Php version ? and are you using xampp or wamp?

Comment: @Narayan Using wamp and 5.5.12 php version

Comment: This is a well-written question and should not require editing.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a compiled PHP extension in the extension directory is not sufficient. Additionally, the extension has to be declared in `php.ini` `extension` directive, e.g. `extension=php_ffmpeg.dll`.

> I am using 64bit system any offical place to look for php_ffmpeg.dll 64bit version ?

There is http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/, but this project is abandoned, so you're probably out of luck. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP for alternative ways to use ffmepg from PHP.